# PHP line pclose(popen(... won't work on Amazon AWS with MAMP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mamp

I have MAMP installed and am running a php script to execute external programs (jar and exe).  Everything works perfectly on my local machine.
However when I put it all on the AWS instance, it just ignores the pclose(popen(...)) line.  I get both log messages and no errors.

```
$command = 'start /B cmd /C '.$this->getCommand().' >NUL 2>NUL';
$this->Log.debug('executing command : '.$command);
pclose(popen($command, 'r'));     
$this->Log.debug('command sent');
```

I'm thinking it might be a permissions issue of some sort?  But I've checked the php.ini and the Apache permissions and everything looks good.  Php is not being told to ignore the popen command.

Update:
I created a test.bat file in the same location

```
echo Hello, World > donald.txt
```

and this executes when called from php, so now I know the pclose(popen()) is working.  The command I am trying to execute is java - jar ... so it must be something to do with permissions running java?

So this works:

```
start /B cmd /C D:/programs/test.bat >NUL 2>NUL
```

and this does not:

```
start /B cmd /C java -Xmx2048m -jar "D:\programs\program.jar" -pm XXX_YYY -t FULL -flag1 -flag2 -k 23 >NUL 2>NUL
```

Comment: are you using `mamp` for windows or for mac?

Comment: for windows.  Everything works fine except that one line

Comment: what is result of `getCommand()`?

Comment: What OS is your AWS instance running?

Comment: Windows Server 2012

Comment: and also I have run the exact command via cmd and it works.  So there is nothing wrong with the command string.

Comment: The command is java -Xmx2048m -jar "D:\programs\my_program.jar" -pm XXX_YYY -t FULL -flag1 -flag2 -k 15 and if run from the command line executes fine.  It also executes fine from PHP on my local desktop running Windows 10 (and the exact same MAMP version).  It fails to run via PHP on the Windows Server 2012 on Amazon Web Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything that is unnecessary, to make your command look like this:

```
$command = 'start /B ' . $this->getCommand();
```

you don't need any redirection as `start /b` will start program without new window.

I have the following:

```
$cmd = 'start /b php {$file} {$bid}';
pclose(popen($cmd, 'r'));
```

And it works on windows perfectly.

BTW, for Linux-based machine you need to run command like this:

```
$command = $this->getCommand() . ' &';
```

to make one script works on `windows` and `Linux` you need something like this:

```
$command = $this->getCommand() . ' &';
if (false !== stripos(PHP_OS, 'win')) {
    $command = 'start /B ' . $this->getCommand();
}
$this->Log.debug('executing command : '.$command);
$p = popen($command, 'r');
sleep(10); //we will give some time for process to start
pclose($p);
$this->Log.debug('command sent');
```

---

**UPDATE**: in the chat we've figured out that the problem was with path to `java.exe`. Apache was unable to find java executable. so the solution was to specify absolute path to `java.exe`:

```
$command = 'start /B C:/Progra~1/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe -Xmx2048m -jar "C:/programs/some-jar-file.jar" -?';
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't get past the pclose(popen($command, 'r')); line.  I'm not running an external php file, but a java program.  My command is java -jar path_to_file.  Everything does work perfectly on my local Windows machine.  It's when it is on AWS which runs Microsoft Windows Server 2012 that it isn't running.

Comment: did you tried to run your command on your server from the command line? is it runs well?

Comment: yup, tried running it through cmd.exe and it runs perfectly.

Comment: oh... try to change `java` to `javaw` in your command... see, you starting process that's immediately killed, so your `java` command won't run... `javaw` starts process without dos-window.

Comment: just tried that, no luck.  I have a log before ("trying") and a log after ("sent") and it doesn't hang on the pclose(...) line, just goes right through it as if nothing was wrong.  The program I'm calling creates a log and lock file (again, runs fine via command line using the exact same full command string).  So I can tell when it does or does not run.

Comment: locally you run it on windows too?

Comment: correct.  On my local desktop (Windows 10) with an identical setup (all ini and conf files the same), it executes great from php.  On Server 2012, everything else (and it is a big project with SQL queries, etc) runs fine ... except the ability to trigger the external program. java -Xmx2048m -jar "D:\programs\my_program.jar" -pm XXX_YYY -t FULL -flag1 -flag2 -k 15.  If I run that from the command line, it executes.  The php script is sending : start /B cmd /C java -Xmx2048m -jar "D:\programs\my_program.jar" -pm XXX_YYY -t FULL -flag1 -flag2 -k 15 >NUL 2>NUL

Comment: try to run on server clean `php` file, with only one command: `passthru('start /B cmd /C java -Xmx2048m -jar "D:\programs\my_program.jar" -pm XXX_YYY -t FULL -flag1 -flag2 -k 15');`

Comment: did not trigger.  I'm thinking it is a permissions issue from the call coming from the PHP server.  I'm checking everything, but it all looks good (although I'm not a Windows security expert and those permissions are confusing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122050/discussion-between-spirit-and-jo-phul).

Comment: The conclusion is to use the full path to java.exe AND removing spaces with C:/Progra~1/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe.  THANKS SPIRIT!